# Does Subversion Support "Extensions"?

Tags: svn

Does anyone know if Subversion supports extensions?

A good example of what I mean would be Apache modules.

Any development resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subversion site has a page dedicated to tools & contrib stuff. [Link](http://subversion.tigris.org/tools_contrib.html)

There you find a lot of stuff to extend subversion. Common hook scripts include email on new commits, checking for proper log message and so on. Since you can write your own hooks (which occur on specified events such as before the actual commit, after the commit...) you can customize it almost as much as you want. The link has a big list of ready-to-use stuff.

### Update for broken link

Subversion is now managed by [Apache](https://subversion.apache.org/) so the above link does not work, you should look at the [Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) *top level link* chapter on [hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) *v1.7 link*.

Answer (score 3):

It supports the concept of [hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/svn-book.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1), which you can use to write your own extensions. I haven't really seen a lot of prepackaged sets of hooks, though.